# Basis for traceless, symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider, for example, the set of of all symmetric, traceless $4 \times 4$ matrices. I'm trying to find a correctly normalized basis for this set. So far, I have

$$s(1)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);s(2)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);s(3)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right); $$ $$s(4)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);s(5)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);s(6)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right); $$  $$ s(7)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right);s(8)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right);s(9)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right); $$  $$s(10)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right), $$

**Is this correct? If yes, these are a basis for the $10$-dimensional representation of $SU(4)$, but how do I need to normalize these matrices propely in the convention, where the Dynkin index $Tr(T_a T_b)$ of the lowest-dimensional representation is $\frac{1}{2} \delta_{ab}$?**

Comment: The space of symmetric $4 \times $ matrices is $10$-dimensional; the space of _traceless_ symmetric $4 \times 4$ matrices is $9$-dimensional. Note that $$s(10) = -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\bigl(s(7) + s(8) + s(9)\bigr).$$That aside, each matrix satisfies $\operatorname{Tr}(T_{a}T_{a}) = 2$, not $\frac{1}{2}$, so it appears each needs to be multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$. Beyond that, I'm afraid I can't help....

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Ah of course! It turns out this was my main problem and you solved it. Thanks!

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Fundamental_representation), you want traceless _Hermitian_ $4 \times 4$ matrices (a.k.a., the Lie algebra of $SU(4)$). The space of these is $15$-dimensional: The six complex entries above the diagonal are "free", and three of the four real diagonal entries are free. The corresponding basis matrices are $s(1)$, ..., $s(6)$; $i$ times corresponding _skew-symmetric_ matrices; and $s(7)$, $s(8)$, $s(9)$. Again, $s(10)$ is redundant.